# Program uninstalled but still on list to remove

Tags: uninstall, mysql

I have installed mysql-server-5.1 from terminal.

Something went wrong and I had to uninstall it, done.

When I type: `sudo apt-get remove mysql` double tab, it still give me a list with some mysql options, trying to remove them I get this message:

Here is the list:

> mysql-common         mysql-server-5.1     mysql-workbench-gpl

And this is the message

> Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree        Reading
>   state information... Done Package mysql-server-5.1 is not installed,
>   so not removed 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not
>   upgraded.

Is it really removed? If so, is there a way to remove it from the list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use **Synaptic Package Manager** (GUI) or **Command Line**

If you do not have Synaptic Package Manager installed, you can install it either, by using Ubuntu Software Center or by typing:

```
sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

[image: Install via the software center]

To more information on how to use Synaptic Package Manager [See this page](http://www.liberiangeek.net/2011/05/how-to-completely-removeuninstall-programs-in-ubuntu-11-04-natty-narwhal/)

**Command line**

To completely remove programs using the command line, you have the following options;

Completely remove package using dpkg

```
sudo dpkg -P package name
```

Remove package and config files, but not dependences using apt-get

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove package name
```

Remove unused dependencies and config files using apt-get

```
sudo apt-get --purge autoremove
```

Remove package and unused dependencies of package, and config files using aptitude

```
sudo aptitude purge package name
```