# Ubuntu still ask to update the package that I have removed

Tags: 12.04, apt, uninstall

Recently I have removed the game 0 AD from my system by using `sudo apt-get remove 0ad`. But when I try to updated the packages by using `sudo apt-get update` followed by `sudo apt-get upgrade`, this is what I get -

```
rympei@Rympei-Desktop:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade 
Reading package lists... Done 
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done 
The following packages have been kept back: 
  linux-headers-generic-pae linux-image-generic-pae wx-common 
The following packages will be upgraded: 
  0ad-data cpio firefox firefox-locale-en linux-libc-dev wx3.0-headers 
  xul-ext-ubufox 
7 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded. 
Need to get 614 MB/616 MB of archives. 
After this operation, 797 MB of additional disk space will be used. 
Do you want to continue [Y/n]?
```

That 0ad package is still there ready for update.

I've tried many ways as mentioned in the following links -

- [Program uninstalled but still on list to remove](https://askubuntu.com/questions/143661/program-uninstalled-but-still-on-list-to-remove)
- [How can you completely remove a package?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151941/how-can-you-completely-remove-a-package)

What I get is the same result as shown above when I try to update the packages.
Is there anything that I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`0ad` and `0ad-data` are two different packages. The first one contains the executables and the second one contains all the graphics files. Thus you will need to remove that too with:

```
sudo apt-get remove 0ad-data
```